# S3 ListObjects not working in Local Stack

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-s3, localstack

I have the code below where I am using `localstack` on my machine. It works when I list the buckets. but it is returning empty array when I do listObjects.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";

let s3 = new AWS.S3({endpoint: 'http://localhost:4572', region: 'us-east-1'});

(async () => {

  // list buckets works, returns all my local buckets
  let buckets = await s3.listBuckets().promise()
  console.log('buckets: ', buckets)

  // this returns empty array
  let listOfobjects = await s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'store-us-east-1'}).promise()
  console.log('listOfobjects: ', listOfobjects);
})()


# ls works via command line, return Invoice.pdf
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 ls s3://store-us-east-1
2020-01-15 18:02:55      82032 Invoice.pdf
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried changing the region to `us-west-1` ? I have read somewhere that `us-east-1` can't be used with api sdk's.

Comment: The list Buckets is working. The listObjects not working

Comment: Also I am not querying an actual s3 bucket. It's a simulated AWS environment using local stack

Answer (score 1):

Right, `listObjects` in localstack is failing due to the bucket address being
`${BUCKET_NAME}.${IP_ADDRESS}` instead of the expected format. All you need is to add this to your S3 instantiation:

```
let s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:4572', 
    region: 'us-east-1',
    sslEnabled: false,
    s3ForcePathStyle: true 
});
```

Also, not that it is critical, but I'd suggest using something like this for the endpoint:

```
endpoint: `http://${process.env.LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME}:4572`
```

Comment: what would that IP_ADDRESS be then? localhost? so in the OP case would be:
s3.listObjects({Bucket: 'store-us-east-1.localhost'}).promise() ?